# After using json2csv I need to now convert it BACK to the JSON with Node

Tags: javascript, json, csv

```
const { Parser, transforms: { unwind }  } = require('json2csv');
 
const myCars = [
  {
    "carModel": "BMW",
    "price": 15000,
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "airbag",
        "color": "white"
      }, {
        "name": "dashboard",
        "color": "black"
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "carModel": "Porsche",
    "price": 30000,
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "airbag",
        "items": [
          {
            "position": "left",
            "color": "white"
          }, {
            "position": "right",
            "color": "gray"
          }
        ]
      }, {
        "name": "dashboard",
        "items": [
          {
            "position": "left",
            "color": "gray"
          }, {
            "position": "right",
            "color": "black"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
 
const fields = ['carModel', 'price', 'items.name', 'items.color', 'items.items.position', 'items.items.color'];
const transforms = [unwind({ paths: ['items', 'items.items'], blankOut: true })];
 
const json2csvParser = new Parser({ fields, transforms });
const csv = json2csvParser.parse(myCars);
 
console.log(csv);
```

Will output

"carModel","price","items.name","items.color","items.items.position","items.items.color"
"BMW",15000,"airbag","white",,
,,"dashboard","black",,
"Porsche",30000,"airbag",,"left","white"
,,,,"right","gray"
,,"dashboard",,"left","gray"
,,,,"right","black"

I want to change all the GRAY to black as the CSV,

What would the best way to be then to convert the CSV back to the original JSON

Comment: Why not just modify the `myCars` array as it exists? Or, stated another way: You already have what you desire in your code called `myCars` - explain why you cannot use that please.

Comment: myCars needs to go into a DB as a CSV in another place have the data changed. EG Gray to Black. Sent back to me as a CSV with the modified data. And I need to change it back to JSON in the original format.

Comment: Sent back from where? A server you control?

Comment: No control over that, its just coming back with modified data in the CSV, fields are the same but the values are new and different.

Comment: The CSV appears to have 6 header fields but the data seems to have 10 fields. You've not described why this is different.

Comment: Data transformation questions should always include the input and expected output of the transformation process. Please edit your question to include both.